# iOS table view having text fields scrolling issue

Tags: objective-c

I have a UITableView which is composed of custom cells. There are 21 cells containing text fields.

When I try to scroll and edit the cells at the bottom of the UITableView, I can't manage to get my cells properly positioned above the keyboard.

Also i created a custom cell class separately for my cells. So keyboard delegates are available on that class only.

I have seen many answers talking about changing view sizes,etc... but none of them has worked nicely so far.

Could anybody clarify the "right" way to do this with a concrete code example?

Comment: have you tried of using uitableviewcontroller class that autometically handles these things.....

Answer (score 0):

There are three approaches to this problem all of which tie into the keyboard did / will show notification....

1. When the keyboard appears, you move the **whole** view (including tableview) up to ensure the selected textfield is shown on screen, you can calculate this by getting the keyboard height (from the notification) and the textfield position.
2. You can resize the tableview so that it is only as big as the portion of the screen **not** covered by the keyboard, again get the height from the notification.
3. You can set the content inset for the tableview (for the bottom value) to the height of the keyboard.

If you need to, when resizing or repositioning the tableview, you may need to set it to scroll the content to the rect of the text field to ensure it is in view...

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Comment: thanks dude but keyboard appears on table view cell class, which only contains content view not the **whole** view is there any method which is called on each cell for row

Comment: They keyboard is a global view, so even though it is being invoked by a text field in a cell, you can observe the keyboard notifications from anywhere you like, in this case from the view controller which contains your table.